# Set dag_run.conf parameters in call to airflow test

Tags: python, airflow

Does anyone know if there is a way to set dag_run.conf parameters when running `airflow test` in the bash prompt?

For example, I've downloaded the [example_trigger_target_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py) from the official airflow repository and I'd like to test the `run_this` task. Usually I would do the following:

`~/$ airflow test example_trigger_target_dag run_this '2018-01-01'`

However running this produces the error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-05-02 10:50:01,154] {models.py:1342} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): run_this> on 2018-01-01 00:00:00
[2018-05-02 10:50:01,262] {models.py:1417} ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 80, in execute
    return_value = self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/annalect/uk_ds_airflow/dags/playpen/example_trigger_target_dag.py", line 56, in run_this_func
    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'
```

I've had a go at using the `task_params` argument however I either have the wrong syntax or it doesn't achieve what I'm after as it produces the same error as above:

`~/$ airflow test --task_params '{"kwargs": {"dag_run": {"conf": {"message": "Hey world"}}}}' example_trigger_target_dag run_this '2018-01-01'`

```
[2018-05-02 11:10:58,065] {models.py:1441} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2018-05-02 11:10:58,070] {models.py:1462} ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'
```

So does anyone know how to test a task that depends on `dag_run.conf` values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `--conf` option for the `airflow test` command but you can work around this by passing parameters to the task's `python_callable`.

In the callable, if `kwargs['test_mode']` is set, you can retrieve the parameters to build a dummy `DagRun` object like so:

```
from airflow.models import DagRun
...

def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['test_mode']:
        kwargs['dag_run'] = DagRun(conf=kwargs['params'])

    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))
```

To test `example_trigger_target_dag`, simply do:

```
airflow test example_trigger_target_dag test_trigger_dagrun "2018-01-01" -tp '{"message":"Hello world"}'
```

and you will get:

```
Remotely received value of Hello world for key=message
```

Now rather than putting test code in your tasks, you can write a decorator. Also since we are just using the `conf` attribute of `DagRun`, we may just as well use a `SimpleNamespace`.
And finally, to avoid a potential key error whilst looking-up `kwargs`, we can use `get` with a default value.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

def allow_conf_testing(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('test_mode', False):
            kwargs['dag_run'] = SimpleNamespace(conf=kwargs.get('params', {}))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@allow_conf_testing
def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I'm misunderstanding the examples. I want to test individual tasks in a dag that is triggered by another, while providing conf values. I am not interested in performing a test run of a trigger controller dag which is what you've provided an example of. You may've answered the question with your suggestion that there is no `--conf` option to `airflow test`.

Comment: The test run of the trigger provides the conf values and runs the individual task. If something fails in the individual task, the test will fail. I don't understand quite why are you not interested in performing a test run of a controller dag. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I'm not interested in testing the controller dag. There are specific tasks within the target dag that I want to test given different conf values. I don't want to have to run the whole target dag to find out how those particular tasks will behave.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's a fine solution for a PythonOperator but is it generalisable to all types of operator? I need a solution that will work for all operators.

Comment: Would you consider subclassing the operators? For bash operators, there is probably a way to achieve a similar result through templating.

Comment: I think that's becoming overkill. I'm really after a generic solution for all operator classes. My DAGs have operators for bash, python, emr, docker, s3 etc. I would like one uncomplicated way to test any of these operators while providing them with a dag_run.conf object.

Comment: It is hard to generalise because `dag_run` is set in the pre-execute method of the task instance. Unless you change this method, `dag_run` will be `None`. That's why I think subclassing is necessary. Note that you can communicate values between tasks with xcom but testing with xcom is not a thing yet.

Comment: Your points are valid and I appreciate the time you've spent on this. Subclassing the operators makes sense but I don't think it's an acceptable solution to have to create subclasses of every operator I want to test with conf values. I still think the accepted solution should be generalisable for all types of operator. Until that exists I'm going to leave the question without an accepted answer.

Comment: Sure. It may be worth putting it as a feature request. AFAICS it would only necessitate a small change to `TaskInstance` and `cli.py`

Comment: Let me know if you need any help putting together a PR. I have a fairly decent idea of how it could work.

Comment: Thnaks ur solution helped me to solve another problem like that , cos it was my first time working on unittest with airflow .

Comment: How do you check if the `dag_run.conf['some_var_key']` is empty or null ?? It fails for a test where I dont specify anything while running the dag. How do you check if dag_run object is None and `dag_run.conf['some_var_key']` isnt just empty string ??

Comment: After some research I believe what I am asking is `How to access the dag_run object outside of any operators` say to define a common parameter for all operators which is passed through dag_run.conf

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade Not sure I understand correctly what you're trying to do. It's probably worth asking a new question.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin So I have an optional input named "reportId" which I get as `report_id = "{{ dag_run.conf['reportId'] }}"` outside any operator. How do I check if `report_id` is Not Empty. I tried null or None or {} but it just dont seem to be empty. So i thought maybe accessing the `dag_run.conf`inside the dag BUT outside any operator should help me.

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade If you are unsure about the presence of a key in a dict, use the method `get(key, default)`. It will prevent key error being thrown.